# Dropping ymd from a ymdhms variable

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

I have a `POSIXct` variable in the form of `"2000-01-01 01:01:01"` (`ymd hms`) but I'd like to drop the `ymd` so I'm left with only the time (i.e. `"01:01:01"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `as.hms` from

```
library(hms)
as.hms(as.POSIXct(str1))
#01:01:01
```

---

If we need only the string version, `format` would work as well

```
format(as.POSIXct(str1), "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "01:01:01"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2000-01-01 01:01:01"
```

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, is there a way to drop hms and keep ymd? I couldn't find a as_ymd function

Comment: @biostatguy12  M__ mentioned about `as.hms` deprecated.  My version still has that.  If you want to drop `hms`, `as.Date(str1)`

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `chron` library:

```r
chron::times(strftime(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 01:01:01"),"%H:%M:%S"))

  # [1] 01:01:01
```